# How to link css file to blade.php laravel file

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Hey i'm using laravel 9 here and im using the SB ADMIN template from bootstrap , i'm making the template as a component `<x-dashboard >...</x-dashboard>`  and i'm passing children inside it ! but i want the children to have it's own css ( not the bootstrap one ) which is in my app.css file i added the head just so i can link the css file to the blade file but still doesn't work any solutions ?

**seeProscpect.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('../css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<x-dashboard >
    <h3 class="changeColor">TRYING CSS</h3>
</x-dashboard>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.css**

```
.changeColor {
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `app.css` located? is it under `public/css/app.css`?

Comment: no it is resources/css/app.css

Comment: Are you using vue? Are you compiling the assets using `npm`? Can you show us your `webpack.mix.js`? The reason why your css is not loading because you have to put it inside the `public `folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **@pushonce** for this purpose.

```
@pushonce('styles')
  <link href="{{ mix('css/tile.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush
```

Comment: Tried exactly like you said , but still no changes ! i tried with @push and also no changes

Comment: Try to add css in head section instead of app.css

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `<head>` after all other CSS script put `@stack('css')`

Ex:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('../css/app.css')}}">
  @stack('css')
</head>
```

Then from your children blade, add @push or @pushonce
Ex:

```
@push('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/blade_style.css')}}" />
<style>
  .body {
     background: #000 !important;
  }
</style>
@endpush

@section
<h1>Children Blade Content</h1>
@endsection
```